# Present UINavigationController as modal, status bar issue

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a nav controller (within a vc) as a modal like so:

`let myNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: someVc)`

`self.present(myNavController, animated: true)`

I'm noticing that it isn't full screen ... the status bar area is black on my 5S device, and on iPhoneX there is similar black space at the top.

It seems like the modal snugs up against the bottom of the status bar's area.

Is there something I need to do to set this space to white? i.e. adjust the status bar style? Extend edge settings?

**5S:**

[image]

---

**iPhoneX:**

[image]

Comment: Can you share more code? Are you using custom transitions ?

Comment: No custom transitions. I'm instantiating my nav controller simply using: `let someNavControllerWithRootVc 
 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: someVc)`

Comment: Then trying to present using the code mentioned in the question: `myVC.present(someNavControllerWithRootVc, animated: true)`

Comment: Did you try to change the statusbar appearance?

Comment: It seems that the nav controller was set to "transparent" ... :S ... #extensionhell

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the UINavigationController.navigationBar was being set to "transparent"!

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

^ fixed the issue!